# How to connect to remote SQL Server from WSL2 using ODBC?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, sqlcmd, unixodbc

I want to connect to a remote SQL Server from WSL2, but I keep getting errors for some reason. I tried connecting using my Windows Host machine without any problem.

**~/.odbc.ini**

```
[MSSQLTest]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.9.so.1.1
server=tcp:server,port
Database=Databasename
Trusted_Connection=yes
TrustServerCertificate=yes
uid=username@domain.com
pwd=password
```

**odbcinst -j**

```
unixODBC 2.3.7
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/test/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

**Errors**

```
test@Desktop:/mnt/c/Users/test$ isql -v mssqltest

[S1000][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSPI Provider: No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)
[S1000][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Cannot generate SSPI context
```

I tried several different changes in the DSN, but none worked. The only thing that changed was the error messages. Then I tried installing `mssql-tools` to use `sqlcmd`, but I got similar errors.

**Errors**

```
test@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Users/test$ sqlcmd -S server -U domain\\username -P password -G
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : SSL Provider: [error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:self signed certificate].
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Client unable to establish the connection.
```

I have no idea what the error above means.

test@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Users/test$ sqlcmd -S **server@example.com** -U domain\username -P password -G
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : SSL Provider: [error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:self signed certificate].
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Client unable to establish connection.

I get a similar error. If I change something in the DSN, I get an error stating `No kerberos credentials available (default cache: FIEL:/tmp/krb5cc_1000). Cannot generate SSPI context.`

I looked up and tried many different solutions suggested on SO and other sites, but I can't seem to get it working. I can, however, ping the server.

Why is it doing this? Why does my connection work from my Windows Host machine but not WSL? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your setup. You might want to check if your admin allows SQL Authentication. Then use the sqlcmd to check if it works for you. You may be able to figure out the solution then.

```
sqlcmd -SXX.XX.XX.XXX -U username -P password -Q "select top 5 * from your_table"
```

Comment: thank you. That was it. I did need SQL Authentication in my account.